# How to set Lambda Context in express js app which are deployed using Claudia

Tags: claudiajs

I have an API server developed using express framework and now I am using Claudia to deploy them to AWS Lambda. Everything is going good and deployed.

New version of Claudia sets the callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop=false and this is exiting my APIs after a response is sent. I am doing some tasks like sending notifications and emails after response is sent and now these tasks are not being executed.

I am unable to find how to set params in lambda context using Claudia to reset the above flag. Is it possible at all?

Basically, I followed the below link to port an existing express app into AWS lambda using claudia.

https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/serverless-express.html

App deployed well except that I want to reset that flag in lambda context which I cannot do it from express app.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/events/number/:number/value', async (request, response) => {

    response.json(request.params);
    console.log('start: ', new Date());
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('end: ', new Date());
});
```

As soon as the response.json is called, start date is logged but lambda doesnt wait till the 'wait' promise is executed. It is executed and end date is logged in the next function call.

Comment: I've built a quick app, using console.log() after a message is returned, to try and copy your issue, but I have been unable to replicate it. Which version of Claudia are you using? Can you please run through your deployment steps? and can you include a quick sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @KMo Claudia v 5.60. updated the question with more details.

Comment: I've followed the tutorial with the same version of Claudia as well, but I am still not hitting the same issue that you are reporting. I added the line console.log(context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop); to the exports handler in the lambda.js file that Claudia generates and it is actually set to true.

Comment: @KMo I see that now, but I was going through this https://claudiajs.com/news/2016/08/04/claudia-api-builder-1.5.1.html which said that is would be 'off' by default, it is an old one though. Also, I added the code I was testing and explained the problem output I am seeing.

Comment: @KMo I guess the only reason I see it is not working in spite of that value being true, is the callback in the app.get doesnt wait for promises to return like the callbacks in array.map or array.for methods